# CNTK TransferLearning.model

Tags: neural-network, cntk

I've been following the **Build your own image classifier using Transfer Learning** tutorial found at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Build-your-own-image-classifier-using-Transfer-Learning#setup).

At the end of the tutorial, it says you use your own data set, which I created by following the example in the tutorial. It successfully completed and created a folder `~/CNTK-Samples-2-3-1/Examples/Image/TransferLearning/Output`, which is expected. Inside this output folder is `predictions.txt`, `predOutput.txt`, and `TransferLearning.model`.

My question is, how do I access `TransferLearning.model`? I'm not sure what to do with it and I can't find anything in the documentation allowing me to alter it or run it.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Once you successfully create your model, you can use it in Python environment (with CNTK) to classify your images. The code should look something like this:

```
#load the trained transfer learning model
trained_model = load_model(model_file)

#for every new image:
#get predictions for a single image
probs = eval_single_image(trained_model, img_file, image_width, image_height)
```